# mark arabic text in css

Tags: html, css, highlight

I have Arabic text that I want to mark it but in Arabic the letters in the word is connected to each other 
when I add tag to highlight letters browser break my word 
any one have idea what I do

An example: 
original word: سلام
I want to highlight just second letter

original word:

```
    <span>سلام</span>
```

add tag after highlight:

```
    <span>س<span class='highlight'>ل</span>ام</span>
```

this change cause show سلام to س‌ل‌ام

Comment: please provide a http://jsfiddle.net example where we can see the problem

Comment: this is example [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xYzB8/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use span use `p` and `span`

```
<p>س<span class='highlight'>ل</span>ام</p>
```

this doesn't break your formatting...

Comment: That doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/4duy5/

Comment: Look... its working http://jsfiddle.net/xYzB8/

Comment: The letters aren't joined.

Comment: I check it too, this doesn't work

Comment: span work in Firefox don't need p tag before it